# Hide disabled time range in jquery timepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery timepicker.

I want to hide particular time range :

following is the code i am using it disables but does not hide the time range

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         $('#durationExample').timepicker({
            'disableTimeRanges': [
                ['1am', '2am'],
                ['3am', '4:01am']
            ]
        });  
    })
```

How do i hide this time range please help me

Answer (score 3):

To hide the disabled time, add following css in your css file :

```
.ui-timepicker-disabled { 
                     display: none; 
                         }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('document').on('change','YourClassName',function(){
       $('.ui-timepicker-disabled').css('display','none');
   })
```